# Icon and color based on index

Tags: flutter, dart

I need some help with my Flutter project because I seem to be stuck at the moment...

Currently I am working on a calendar app and I want to create some event 'categories'. Based on an index, I would like a certain icon to be displayed. Currently there are only two icons. A filled and unfilled circle. See the link for the screenshot below.

[Current icons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NJW9D.png)

The icon is selected based on a method from the following code.

**color-picker.dart:**

```
class _ColorPicker extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _ColorPickerState();
  }
}

class _ColorPickerState extends State<_ColorPicker> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AlertDialog(
      content: Container(
          width: double.maxFinite,
          child: ListView.builder(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
            itemCount: _colorCollection.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return ListTile(
                contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
                leading: Icon(
                    index == _selectedColorIndex
                        ? Icons.lens
                        : Icons.trip_origin,
                    color: _colorCollection[index]),
                title: Text(_colorNames[index]),
                onTap: () {
                  setState(() {
                    _selectedColorIndex = index;
                  });

                  // ignore: always_specify_types
                  Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 200), () {
                    // When task is over, close the dialog
                    Navigator.pop(context);
                  });
                },
              );
            },
          )),
    );
  }
}
```

I want icons to show based on the category like I tried setting up in the code below.

**Calendar.dart**

```
class Category {
  String eventCategory;
  IconData eventIcon;

  Category(this.eventCategory, this.eventIcon);
}

List<Category> _categories = [
  Category('Productivity', Icons.add_to_queue),
  Category('Self Development', Icons.bolt_rounded),
  Category('Task', Icons.check),
];
```

If someone could help me figure out how to replace the part of the code where I can only pick 2 icons, that would be very much appreciated!

Thanks in advance for looking!

Kind regards,

Robert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't get you well. I guess you want to show icons for each category and when one is selected by `onTap` method you want to change color of icon when selected. I have done just that. Inform me if there is something you want me to change.

**Here is my code snippet. Copy and paste to see the effect:**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ColorPickerScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _ColorPickerScreenState();
  }
}

class Category {
  String eventCategory;
  IconData eventIcon;

  Category(this.eventCategory, this.eventIcon);
}

class _ColorPickerScreenState extends State<ColorPickerScreen> {
  List<Category> _categories = [
    Category('Productivity', Icons.add_to_queue),
    Category('Self Development', Icons.bolt_rounded),
    Category('Task', Icons.check),
  ];

  int? _selectedColorIndex; // change here to `int _selectedColorIndex` if your flutter sdk version is older than null safety version
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AlertDialog(
      content: Container(
          width: double.maxFinite,
          child: ListView.builder(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
            itemCount: _categories.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return ListTile(
                contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
                leading: Icon(_categories[index].eventIcon,
                    color: index == _selectedColorIndex
                        ? Colors.green
                        : Colors.red),
                title: Text(_categories[index].eventCategory),
                onTap: () {
                  setState(() {
                    _selectedColorIndex = index;
                  });

                  /// This part is not needed
                  // // ignore: always_specify_types
                  // Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 200), () {
                  //   // When task is over, close the dialog
                  //   Navigator.pop(context);
                  // });
                },
              );
            },
          )),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick help! Even though it was vaguely described because it was tough for me to explain, you nailed it :)

Comment: @Robert  no problem.

Comment: "I have done just that" is not at all useful for future readers who may encounter this. you should instead explain what you did to achieve the desired results.